# Rust lifetimes : Static reference lives to short to be fed into a function?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm discovering rust and have a hard time with lifetimes.

For example, I am experimenting with GUIs a little :

```
#[macro_use]extern crate native_windows_gui as nwg;

use nwg::{Ui, Event, EventArgs};

nwg_template!(
    head: setup_ui<&'static str>,
    controls: [
        ("MainWindow", nwg_window!(title="Test1"; size=(180,50))),
        ("SetButton", nwg_button!(parent="MainWindow"; visible=false)),
        ("BackButton", nwg_button!(parent="MainWindow"; text="<"; position=(10,10); size=(30,30))),
        ("Text", nwg_textbox!(parent="MainWindow"; readonly=true; position=(40,10); size=(100,30))),
        ("NextButton", nwg_button!(parent="MainWindow"; text=">"; position=(140,10); size=(30,30)))
    ];
    events: [
        ("SetButton", "Set", Event::Click, |app,_,_,_| {
            let display = nwg_get_mut!(app; ("Text", nwg::TextBox));
            let index = nwg_get!(app; ("Index", &str));
            display.set_text(**index);
        }),
        ("BackButton", "Back", Event::Click, |_,_,_,_| {}),
        ("NextButton", "Next", Event::Click, |_,_,_,_| {})
    ];
    resources: [];
    values: [
        ("Index", "Test")
    ]
);

fn create_ui(data: &'static str) -> Result<Ui<&'static str>, nwg::Error> {
   let app: Ui<&'static str>;

    match Ui::new() {
        Ok(ui) => { app = ui; },
        Err(e) => { return Err(e) }
    }

    if let Err(e) = setup_ui(&app) {
        return Err(e);
    }

    app.pack_value(&"Data", &data);
    app.trigger(&"SetButton", Event::Click, EventArgs::None);

    if let Err(e) =app.commit() {
        Err(e)
    } else {
        Ok(app)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let data = "Foo";
    let _ui = create_ui(data).expect("Oups");
    nwg::dispatch_events();
}
```

I don't understand why in the function `create_ui`, `data` doesn't live long enough to be fed in `app.pack_value()`.

It seems to me that the `'static` lifetime would make it survive long enough.

But the compiler insits it dies at the end of `create_ui` and therefore cannot be used as `app.pack_value("Data", &data);`

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: "..it dies *at the end of* create_ui.."

Comment: "What am I doing wrong ?" You're complaining about an error without giving the text of the error message. We can't help without all the information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the exact error, it's hard to be sure, but my guess is this:

```
fn create_ui(data: &'static str) -> Result<Ui<&'static str>, nwg::Error>
```

The parameter `data` will borrow a string of static lifetime. That is, the thing it points to (the string data) has static lifetime, but the reference itself has the lifetime of the function. Now let's look at the function in the `native_windows_gui` crate:

```
fn pack_value<T: Into<Box<T>> + 'static>(&self, id: &ID, value: T)
```

The parameter `value` has to have static lifetime. There are some other requirements too, but they're not relevant. Now back to your code:

```
app.pack_value(&"Data", &data);
```

You're passing `pack_value` **a reference to** `data`, which was already a reference. That is, the argument you're passing has type `&&'static str`. The outer reference (the one you're passing) **doesn't** have static lifetime: it lives only as long as your function.

The equivalent in C++ would be something like

```
result_type create_ui(static char *str) {
    Ui app = ...;
    app.pack_value(&"Data", &str);
}
```

This would compile fine in C++, but you're not passing the string, you're passing the address of the argument. This would compile fine but the behaviour would be undefined, and it would depend on what else is on the stack when that pointer is dereferenced. In Rust, instead of a hard-to-debug question, the compiler tells you what's wrong.

The solution is the same as it would be for C++: you need to remove the extra `&`, and pass the same reference you received:

```
app.pack_value(&"Data", data);
```